# Paging in MVC 4 will reduce the page performance?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have done the paging with the help of this tutorial
  [Paging](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I am using a view model,my question is while I am clicking on the page number it is going to the "ActionMethod" and retrieving 2k records from Database, and filtering 10 records (`ViewModel.Summaries.ToPagedList(page, pagesize);`) showing in the view.  If I click on next page number same cycle is happening.

So is it reduce the performance of the page? Because it is hitting the database every time and fetching 2k records and then filtering?

ActionMethod:

```
       public ActionResult Details(int page=1,int pagesize=10)
       {
           ViewModel ViewModel = this.Gateway.GetDetails(Id);//2k records r getting from DB

         ViewModel.SummariesPaged = ViewModel.Summaries.ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
         return View("Details", ViewModel);

        }
```

View Model :

```
      public class  ViewModel
      {
          public  List<SummaryModel> Summaries { get; set; }

          public PagedList.IPagedList<SummaryModel> SummariesPaged { get; set; 
      }     
    }
```

Comment: Possibly.  It depends on what `this.Gateway.GetDetails(Id)` is doing.

Comment: assume "this.Gateway.GetDetails(Id)" is doing good, but every time action method is hitting DB and fetching 2k records

Answer (score 0):

You should only get records from the database you want to display for this you can create method like following.

```
public IList<SomeType> ToPagedList(int pageNo, int pageSize)
{
    return db.Summaries.Skip((pageNo-1)  * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

**Update**

Sorry, I did not noticed you are already using `PagedList.Mvc` so no need to create  a method like above.

You just need to invoke ToPageList method on IQuerable without invoking `ToList` method. When ever linq will encounter `ToList` Method it will execute query against database then after query would result in **linq to object** not **linq to sql**.

so here is solution for you. Use like following.

```
db.Summaries.ToPageList(page, pageSize);
```

You may apply filter and order the summaries if you want but do not call to list before ToPagedList method.

Comment: means i should not call like this "ViewModel ViewModel = this.Gateway.GetDetails(Id); " before ToPagedList(); @Jenish

Comment: @RaviTeja You may call it but make `Summaries ` as  `IQueryable` and do not invoke  ToList on summaries entity while assigning it ot Summaries property of viewmodel.

Comment: IQueryable<<SummaryModel> Summaries { get; set; } like this??

Comment: this statement is getting 2k records "ViewModel ViewModel = this.Gateway.GetDetails(Id);" every time, will it impact on page performance?? @Jenish

Comment: @RaviTeja Yes That's what I mentioned in my answer if you would take 2k records on every page request there would be performance issue. just take as much records as you want to show on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests several answers with different levels of details.

First, does `PagedList.Mvc` actually read 2000 records when you only need 10? The answer is no. Entity Framework supports methods `IQueryable<T>.Take` and `IQueryable<T>.Skip` and translates them to SQL constructions like `LIMIT`, `TOP`, CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`, `OFFSET FETCH`, and other (depends on an engine and its version). So you should just use the `PagedList.Mvc` as it described in the documentation.

Second, does SQL server actually processes 2000 records when you only need 10? The answer is yes. Server uses B-tree to store tables and indices. Although B-tree allows get *n*-th record quickly, this feature implies overhead and is not implemented in most popular modern servers. I've seen the implementation in Berkley DB only, and this feature is enabled/disabled there.

So, if you ask the server to give you records with numbers from 1,000,000 to 1,000,010, it actually scans and skips 1,000,000 records.

This is not a problem, if the number of records in the table is not very large (say, less than a million). But if you have 10 or 100 millions records, you may expect performance problems.